# Button and Image Alignment issues in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a UIBarbuttonItem that I am currently designing based off of a layout that I have done.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LocationManager: UIBarButtonItem {
    var viewController: MainViewController?

    lazy var customButton : UIButton = {
        let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        customButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "downArrow"), for: .normal)
        customButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, -10)
        guard let customFont = UIFont(name: "NoirPro-SemiBold", size: 20) else {
            fatalError("""
        Failed to load the "CustomFont-Light" font.
        Make sure the font file is included in the project and the font name is spelled correctly.
        """
            )
        }
        customButton.semanticContentAttribute = UIApplication.shared
            .userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? .forceLeftToRight : .forceRightToLeft
        customButton.titleLabel?.font = customFont
        customButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        return customButton
    }()



    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupViews()
    }

    @objc func setupViews(){
        customView = customButton

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

I correctly do the job of using both an image and title and setting the image insets for the button and on load the appearance is great. However, when I leave the screen and come back it seems as though everything is thrown out of wack the image gets moved back and sometimes there will be two images and one will have a distorted size.

Is there anything wrong with my custom button implementation that I am missing.

I have included images for before and after[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make your custom button class, then make title and image by adding subviews. In this case UIImageView and UILabel. Because UIButton inherits from UIView you can easy do this. I've never had problems using this way.

Here is the code I've written for you:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var customButton: CustomButton = {
    let button = CustomButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50,
                                            y: 200,
                                            width: view.frame.width - 100,
                                            height: 50))
    // This mask for rotation
    button.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin,
                             .flexibleRightMargin,
                             .flexibleTopMargin,
                             .flexibleBottomMargin]
    button.attrTitleLabel.text = "San Francisco, CA"
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(chooseCity), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.addSubview(customButton)
}

@objc func chooseCity() {
    print("Choose city button has pressed")
}

}

class CustomButton: UIButton {

private let arrowImageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
private let sideOffset: CGFloat = 10

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = .white

    addSubview(attrTitleLabel)
    addSubview(arrowImageView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

lazy var attrTitleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "NoirPro-SemiBold", size: 20)
    label.textColor = .black
    return label
}()

lazy var arrowImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "arrow_down")
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return iv
}()

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    arrowImageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width - arrowImageSize.width - sideOffset,
                                  y: self.frame.height/2 - arrowImageSize.height/2,
                                  width: arrowImageSize.width,
                                  height: arrowImageSize.height)

    attrTitleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: sideOffset, y: 0, width: self.frame.width - sideOffset*2 - arrowImageSize.width, height: self.frame.height)
}

}
```

How it looks:

[image]

Comment: so if i leave and come back will the orientation not be messed up with this setup

Comment: there will be some bugs with orientation.. give me few minutes and I will edit post that fix these bugs

Comment: also i get no text just an arrow

Comment: with the text stuck inside of it\

Comment: check for the font... are you sure you have this?

Comment: did you see my update for what your code resulted in

Comment: is all that frame code necessary to put them right next to each other

Comment: I won't write all code for you. Check frames or you can use constraints. This way of adding title and image 100% works. Create a new project, copy and paste all code from post. You'll see how it works and inside this small project you can customise your button. Then just set same settings to your main project

Comment: so this aswer doesnt work now i can't click the button